# Select SQL with nullable integer variable and "in" at the where clause in asp dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dataset, nullable

I have a SQL query like bellow at the dataset in asp, naming "`GetData`":

```
select * 
from TABLE1 
where (TABLE1.ID in (select RecID from TABLE2 where TABLE2.RecID = @RecID))
   or (@RecID is null)
```

But when I use this method to retrieve data from database:

```
?int RecID;
GetData(RecID);
```

I get an error:

> the best overloaded method match for datasettableadapters.GetData(int)has some invalid arguments

So it doesn't accept nullable arguments for `@RecID`, but when I change the SQL statement to this:

```
select * 
from TABLE1 
where (TABLE1.ID in (select RecID from TABLE2 where TABLE2.RecID = @RecID))
```

it accepts the nullable `RecID` argument.

But I want to retrieve all data from `TABLE1` (without its where clause) when the argument `@RecID` is NULL.

Comment: you should not check variable is null or not in side of query. @RecID. Please check this before excuting query. or else change your query. I didnt get what excatly you want in result but at first glance i found your query is wrong.

Comment: what result u want to achive. why ur checking @RecID is null.

Comment: so why this query is not wrong?! : select * from TABLE1 WHERE RecID=@RecID OR @RecID IS NOt NULL

Comment: actually my query has more where conditions and i use the problem conditions for short clause.

Comment: i want if @RecID is Null retreive all data from Table! withaout any where clause condition.

Comment: There are no relation between OR @RecID IS NOt  with Table1 table. So its not valid to put Or stetment at the end.. check the result what u need then u write ur qury